# Wrong margins on even pages using Memoir

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm trying to customize the textblock size in a Memoir document, however, both `\settextblocksize` and a simple `\setlength{\textwidth}`, `\setlength{\textheight}` cause wrong margins on even pages.

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\textheight}{23.45cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{11.85cm}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Output for second and third page:

[image]
[image]

How to fix this?

The magic command `\checkandfixthelayout` does not help with this particular problem.

Comment: Often, memoir users decide on margins and let the typeblock set itself. Commands used include `\setstocksize`, `\settrimmedsize`, `\setlrmarginsandblock`, and `\setulmarginsandblock`. These are in sections 2.3 and 2.4 of the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike mention, you are messing with the text width but there are many other parameters that control the layout.

This works

```
\settypeblocksize{23.45cm}{11.85cm}*
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{0.75}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

Note that if you leave out the `\setlrmargins` then you get what you showed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation, this solves my problem! I actually expected Memoir to recalculate the margins automatically when using its `\settypeblocksize` command.

Comment: How would it know the margins you want?